# TextAnalyticsAPI.Sentiment() method returning positive sentiment for a negative phrase

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Following phrase was detected with a sentimental score of .78, while I'd expect a low score. Can someone explain why?

"An Indian restaurant that I would avoid at all costs. A place that's worse than a fast food joint but masquerades as a high end restaurant. Nothing is worth eating, not even a simple naan. Thanks for the pricey crap, but no thanks."

Comment: This is the sample code I was trying https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Text-Analytics/QuickStarts/CSharp. I had to change it to AzureRegions.Westcentralus to make it work.

Comment: Hmm... it's as if they inverted the meaning of the scores... close to 0 for positive sentiment, close to 1 for negative

Comment: Nope. True positive recognized negative sentiments has score close to 0 something like 0.1.